# How can I catch a 404 status exception thrown by simpleHttp of Http.Conduit

Tags: haskell, http-status-code-404, http-conduit

I'm trying to download all png files contained in an html file.
I have trouble catching 404 status exceptions though, instead my program just crashes.

Here is some sample to demonstrate:

```
import Network.HTTP.Conduit
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L

main = do
    let badUrl = "http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/WRONG.png"    
    imgData <- (simpleHttp badUrl) `catch` statusExceptionHandler  
    L.writeFile "my.png" imgData

statusExceptionHandler ::  t -> IO L.ByteString
statusExceptionHandler e = (putStrLn "oops") >> (return L.empty)
```

My "oops" message never prints, instead app crashes with:

> StatusCodeException (Status {statusCode = 404, statusMessage = "Not Found"}) [("Content-Type","text/html; charset=UTF-8"),("X-Content-Type-Options","nosniff"),("Date","Fri, 27 Jan 2012 03:10:34 GMT"),("Server","sffe"),("Content-Length","964"),("X-XSS-Protection","1; mode=block")]

What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**

Following Thoma's advice, I changed my code to the following snippet and now have proper exception handling in place.

```
main = do
    let badUrl = "http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/WRONG.png"    
    imgData <- (simpleHttp badUrl) `X.catch` statusExceptionHandler  
    case imgData of x | x == L.empty -> return () 
                      | otherwise    -> L.writeFile "my.png" imgData

statusExceptionHandler ::  HttpException -> IO L.ByteString
statusExceptionHandler (StatusCodeException status headers) = 
    putStr "An error occured during download: "
    >> (putStrLn $ show status)
    >> (return L.empty)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should probably read the [Marlow paper on extensible exceptions](http://community.haskell.org/~simonmar/papers/ext-exceptions.pdf).  The original [`catch`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:catch), exported by Prelude and used in your code snipt, only works for IOError's.  The http-conduit code is throwing exceptions of a different type, [HttpException](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/http-conduit/1.2.0/doc/html/Network-HTTP-Conduit.html#g:10) to be exact. (there is some dynamic typing going on via the Typeable class, see the paper).

The solution?  Use catch from [Control.Exception](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Exception.html) and only catch the error types you want to handle (or `SomeException` for all of them).

```
import Network.HTTP.Conduit
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L
import Control.Exception as X

main = do
    let badUrl = "http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/WRONG.png"
    imgData <- (simpleHttp badUrl) `X.catch` statusExceptionHandler
        L.writeFile "my.png" imgData

statusExceptionHandler ::  SomeException -> IO L.ByteString
statusExceptionHandler e = (putStrLn "oops") >> (return L.empty)
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem. I agree with catching only specific exceptions (that was my next step, I just never got there).

Answer (score 8):

In addition to Thomas's answer, you could tell `http-conduit` not to throw an exception by overriding the `checkStatus` record of your `Request` type.

Comment: you made my day, as usual (: